# Eigenvalues and eigenvector of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
11 & 4 & 14 & \\
4 & -1 & 10 &  \\
14 & 10 & 8 &  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

1.One solution would be to compute the 3 minors of the matrix then solve them until i have a equation to the power of 3, then use newton, divide the equation with (x-solution) and compute the other two eigenvalues. But this is rather time consuming.

2.But now I immediately know that this matrix is symmetric and the Spectral Theorem for symmetric matrices implies that $Au_{k}=\lambda_{k}u_{k}$. But U has to be a orthonormal basis for the eigenvectors x of A, therefore I can't find them.

My answer is if I could compute it faster than using my first concept with Newton!

THanks!

Comment: The equation for eigenvalues of the matrix is of degree $3$, therefore you can find the roots explicitly.

Comment: Find the roots of characteristic equation $|A-\lambda I_3|=0$ would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}
11 & 4 & 14 & \\
4 & -1 & 10 &  \\
14 & 10 & 8 &  \\
\end{pmatrix}\implies $$

$$\implies\det(tI-A)= \begin{vmatrix}
t-11 & -4 & -14 & \\
-4 &t+1 & -10 &  \\
-14 & -10 & t-8 &  \\
\end{vmatrix}=t^3-18t^2-243t=t(t+9)(t-27)$$

Now calculate corresponding eigenvectors, for example:

$$\lambda=-9: \begin{cases}&I\;\;\;\;\;-20x-4y-14z=0\\
&II\;\;\;\,-4x-8y-10z=0\\
&III\;\;-14x-10y-17z=0\end{cases}\implies III=\frac12I+II \stackrel{-\frac12II}\implies$$

$$\begin{cases}&A\;\;-20x-4y-14z=0\\
&B\;\;\;\;\;\;\,2x+4y\;+\;\;\,5z=0\end{cases}\stackrel{A+B}\implies-18x-9z=0\implies x=-\frac12z\implies$$

$$\implies y=\frac{-2x-5z}2=\frac{z-5z}2=-z\stackrel{\text{example of e.v.}}\implies\begin{pmatrix}\;1\\\;2\\\!\!-2\end{pmatrix}$$

and etc. Do something similar as the above for the other two eigenvalues and you'll get other two eigenvectors which together with the one above will yield a basis of $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ (why?).

You may want to orthonormalize the basis you\ll get in order to obtain an orthogonal diagonalization (why is this possible?), but that's already not part of the questiopn.